# C++ "using namespace" retroactive visibility?

Tags: c++, templates, namespaces

I've got some code set up to detect either a method or function of the same name, and call the appropriate one, or `abort` if neither exists. I have noticed, however, that if the compilation-unit that calls this method imports the namespace via `using`, then the result is infinite recursion rather than an `abort`. It seems like the `using` declaration in a source-file is retroactively adding to the global-namespace as seen by the preceding headers, which I find disturbing.

I have isolated the issue for illustration here as best I can (compiling with MSVC2017):

```cpp
// HEADER

namespace ns1
{
  template<typename U>
  inline auto foo_free(const U& u, int)
    -> decltype(foo(u))
  {
    return foo(u);
  }

  template<typename U>
  inline uint64_t foo_free(const U& u, char)
  {
    abort();
    return 0;
  }

  template<typename U>
  inline auto foo_method(const U& u, int)
    -> decltype(u.foo())
  {
    return u.foo();
  }

  template<typename U>
  inline uint64_t foo_method(const U& u, char)
  {
    return ns1::foo_free(u, 0);
  }
}

namespace ns2
{
  template<typename U>
  inline uint64_t foo(const U& u)
  {
    return ns1::foo_method(u, 0);
  }
}

// SOURCE

// removing this line results in expected behavior
using namespace ns2;

struct atype {};

bool detect_foo_confusion(void)
{
  atype a;
  const atype* cap = &a;
  ns2::foo(cap); // problem
  return true;
}
```

The only solution I can think of is to name `ns2::foo` or the other `foo` something different, but this has some undesirable consequences on how the calling code looks.

1. What's going on here? Does `using namespace` always work this way, or is this a templates thing?
2. Is there a way for me to isolate `ns1` from `ns2` or otherwise keep the same name?

Comment: If commenting the `template<typename U> inline uint64_t foo_free(const U& u, char)` overload (the function calling `abort()`) then MSVC build while both GCC and Clang fails ([see on the compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/sre9b7)). So the bigger question then becomes: Is this a bug in the MSVC++ compiler, or is it correct and both GCC and Clang are buggy?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Hm. That does seem to suggest that the other compilers do not share this issue. The `abort()` function exists to convert a compiler-error into a runtime one, so if MSVC is compiling even without it, then that seems like a bug. If no other explanation is offered, I'll send them a bug report.

Comment: It does seem odd. Also note that this "bug" exists even in the latest version available on the compiler explorer site.

Comment: `using` directives don't "import" namespaces. They cause the compiler to treat names in a namespace as CANDIDATES to match names using in subsequent code. Ambiguity is the most common problem (a using directive causes a name in a namespace to unexpectedly be an equally good match for another name).  I suspect you're seeing a less common case of a name in the namespace becoming a better match than it would otherwise be.  You might try stepping through both versions with a debugger to identify where flow of execution (e.g. a function called) changes between them.